# Unexpected "'String"' error (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php

Today i was working with some codes when I met this error to make it simplify I have made an simple code which returns this error:

```
$i=1;
echo  $i*5."<br/>";
```

**Error**

```
syntax error, unexpected '"<br/>"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'
```

Here I am trying to multiply an integer variable with an integer value and then add some string afterwords.
the solution I found to escape this error is to simply replace `$i*5` by `5*$i` but it my question is why does this happens.In my scope ov view there is no syntax error but if there is any please let me know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for the error is the `.` after `5` which makes compiler confused whether 5 is an integer or an floating value i.e it expects some digits after `.` but it gets `"<br/>"`
You can add an space after the digit so that the compiler gets to know that number is over like this :

```
$i=1;
echo  $i*5 ."<br/>";
```

Comment: Depending on coding style, a space is a very weak separator. Parentheses would help! `echo  ($i*5)."<br/>";`

Comment: Ya but in such cases an space would do the job.

Comment: What if your coding style forbids the use of spaces around a dot? The more permanent solution that is also resistant against "formatting" issues is with parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is either

```
echo  $i*5, "<br/>";
// You can echo more than one expression, separating them with comma.
```

or

```
echo  $i*5 . "<br/>";
// Notice the space.
// 5. is interpreted as ( float ) 5
```